# Store, fetch and map images from amazon webservice in MVC Dotnet Application

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-mvc-3, amazon-ec2

I'm new to Amazon webservice. I created a instance in AWS EC2 to publish my website.Now I have an requirement.
I have resources where each resource must be able to choose the images(as profile picture)during runtime. I want to fetch the images from amazon storage and map in the already developed mvc.net application. I had this idea of storing the images in amazonS3(via budget) but I need to know how to fetch them during run time which enables resources to choose their profile picture from the uploaded images in bucket.

Please letme know if there is anyother way to store and fetch profile pictures using amazon to my mvcdotnet application?

Answer (score 0):

Store the Original Image file in S3 Standard option.Store the reproducible images like thumbs etc in the S3 Reduced Redundancy option (RRS) to save costs. Store the Meta data about images including the S3 URL mapping in Amazon RDS and query them whenever needed from EC2.